# Format a date given from a json

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, symfony

I search a way to format a date given from a json response. Currently I can pass the date via json response into both format :

the string format:

```
{"date":"2016-11-25T11:24:54+0100"}
```

or the object format:

```
"date":{"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/Paris","location":{"country_code":"FR","latitude":48.86666,"longitude":2.33333,"comments":""}},"offset":3600,"timestamp":1480069808}}
```

I have to format one of this two json formats into that format:
`dd/mm/aaaa`, example: 25/11/2016

This operation must be done in my view, with jQuery/js, or in the controller before send the json reponse:

```
/*            $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();      here the code for fomat the date into string
            $callback = function ($dateTime) {
                return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime
                    ? $dateTime->format(\DateTime::ISO8601)
                    : '';
            };
            $normalizer->setCallbacks(array('date' => $callback));*/

            $normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('article'));
            $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
            $dataJSON = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

            $response = new Response();
            $response->setContent($dataJSON);
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            return $response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use PHPs build in DateTime class like

```
<?php

$date = new Datetime('2016-11-25T11:24:54+0100');
var_dump($date->format('d.m.Y h:i:s')); // string(19) "25.11.2016 11:24:54"
```

Answer (score 1):

Independently how your controller sends the data, in your view (presentation) you can format it via [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

For example:

```
// Your controller date timestamp
const timestamp = 1480070762;
moment().unix(timestamp).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

I suggest you your controller to act as an API and all views to have flexability to choose the presentation format of the date.